# Безопасность сайта за Cloud Web Application Firewall

Tags: безопасность, cloudflare

Сайт располагается за WAF cloudflare, следственно все запросы через CF определенным образом фильтруются. Однако бывают ситуации, когда в интернет утекает реальный IP сервера, за счет чего злоумышленник может в обход WAF посылать запросы. Как настроить сервер так, чтобы он брал соединения только от CF?

Простая проверка показала, что CF дергает сайт с разных IP, следственно перечислить  эти IP в php сразу нельзя, разве что добыть где-то их базу

Comment: Вот, добывайте https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/ А лучше с утечками боритесь ещё

Comment: И прописывать ip надо не в php, а в фаерволе, чтобы чужие запросы до php вообще не доходили

Comment: там не все адреса перечисляются

Comment: Можно пример такого, который не перечислен?

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо) нашел библиотеку на гите